# Difference between convention for matrix multiplication of vector in algebra and computer science

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra, convention

In algebra, we typically write $Ax=b$ when we wish to multiply a $n$ dimensional $x$ vector by matrix $A$, requiring $A$ of course to have $n$ *columns*.

Yet, in computer science, I typically see $xA=b$, with $A$ having $n$ *rows*.

Of course, any "math" matrix can be transposed to give you its "computer science" matrix, so this is a matter of convention.  Why? Is this for computational efficiency? For clarity? Tradition?

Similarly, the scalar product of two vectors is typically expressed $x \cdot y$ in math, but $x^Ty$ in computer science.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't associate the "row vector" convention to Computer Science more than to other fields and I believe that it is globally much less frequent. It probably arose just because the two conventions are possible.

Computational efficiency cannot be an explanation (or more precisely cache-friendliness), as there exist languages used in scientific applications that store matrices in row-major as well as column-major order.

$x^Ty$ is a kind of notational abuse, as it corresponds to a $1\times1$ matrix, and not exactly a scalar. The dot is more appropriate.

Comment: I voted for closing because this question is off-topic here.

Comment: $x^Ty$ is also strangely inconsistent with this supposed row-first convention in computer science: if you're using row vectors, surely you want to write $x \cdot y$ as $xy^T$, if you're going to do something like that.